# Openlayers - Move Scale Text to a DIV

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In my Openlayers map, I am trying to move the scale text (OpenLayers.Control.Scale) to a div outside the map but it is not working.  I can get the mouse control to work but not the Scale.

Javascript:

```
map.addControl(
new OpenLayers.Control.Scale({
        div: scale
    })
);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="statusbar">
        <div id="coords" class="innerstatusbar"></div>
        <div id="scale" class="innerstatusbar"></div>
        <div id="output" class="innerstatusbar"></div>
        <div id="blank" class="outerstatusbar"></div>
        <div id="something" class="innerstatusbar">Something</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
map.addControl(
new OpenLayers.Control.Scale(
        'scale'
    )
);
```

It takes the DOM-Elements ID as a string without curly brackets. If you want to add geodesic property, you would write it like so:

```
map.addControl(
new OpenLayers.Control.Scale(
        'scale',
        {geodesic: true}
    )
);
```

I struggled with that aswell and still think its sometimes weird how parameters are put into the constructors :D